# Image with only the red component from RGB 565

Tags: c++, c, colors, rgb

Hello, here's a part of the code which Iam using,

```
                b=(byte2&0xF8)<<8;  //F8=11111000   5
                g=(byte2&0xFC)<<3;  //FC=11111100   6
                r=(byte2&0xF8)>>3;  //F8=11111000   5
                grisColor=(r)|(g)|(b);
```

it takes a picture with an OV7670 camera in RGB 565, what do I have to modify in order to take a picture with only the red component?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Adding tags for the language may help people who know what you are talking about find your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just comment out the end of the last line:

```
grisColor=(r);//|(g)|(b);
```

and/or set `g` and `b` to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the 5 bits of red, the next question is, do you want the output in grayscale (e.g. single octet), or RGB565 with just the red filled in (and green and blue zero), or RGB565 grayscale, or RGB24, ...?

Comment: Yes Iam getting BGR. Yes, I would like the output in 8-bit grayscale.Thanks

Comment: so if you have b00011111 in `r` already, you could use that directly except you wouldn't have the range 0-255 so you can easily scale it, e.g. rounded: `( (int)r * 255 + 15 ) / 31;`

Comment: That's a rather slow way to scale to the range. The fast way that's usually done is: `(r<<3 | r>>2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your goal is to get an 8bit grayscale image from the ov7670.
 You would get better results by setting the ov7670 to output yuv422 and "convert" that data to grayscale (Just use the Y component and ignore the U and V components).

I have a github repository that contains some useful functions for configuring the ov7670.
Check out the register list named yuv422_ov7670 https://github.com/ComputerNerd/ov7670-no-ram-arduino-uno/blob/master/ov7670_regs.h